# Does Mac OS X keep a log of network connection addresses and dates/times?

Tags: macos, networking, connection, recording, time

I have lost a file containing my hours worked for a particular client over the last month.

However, I am always connected to their wireless network whilst I am working for them.

Is there anyway that I can view a record of connection start times, durations or disconnection times for a given wireless network in OS X?

That way I can bill them accurately rather than just making up a figure!

Thanks

Pete

Comment: Console.app is the quick and dirty solution but for longer term issues, I found this tool useful on OS X http://superuser.com/a/980399/137921 ... It's $10 though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the various logs in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`.

`system.log` and `/private/var/log/kernel.log` look best (the latter was mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/190368/how-can-i-turn-my-airport-on-off-with-speech-recognition-on-my-mac/190428#190428) for a similar issue). Just search them for "en1" or whatever your network's interface is (`en0` is usually wired, `en1` wireless).

These don't say, however, what the network's name was. But if you know the times roughly (check your email archive and version control software, for example), it might help a great deal.

Comment: If anyone else can offer any other insights (maybe a log of all connections made to a particular ip address or possibly a way of checking the router for a connection history with my laptop) I would be very grateful

Comment: @user56876 You might want to tell us the router model. And it only works if you have access to it at your client's.

Comment: Daniel, I am looking through system.log, but can only see records from today and yesterday. Presumably there is an archive older logs that I can access in the same way. Could you tell me how I can access those? Thanks again. p.s. I can get access to the router, the model is 'D-Link Wireless 108G MIMO ADSL 2/2+ Router'. I'm not an IT professional but know enough to log onto the router's setup screen

Comment: @user Try the `/private/var/log/system.log.X.bz2` files, they go back further. My kernel log goes back to when I installed the system in June, you might be more successful there.

Comment: @user [This](ftp://ftp.dlink.com/Gateway/di634M/Manual/DI634M_manual_100.zip) is the router's manual. Page 54 describes where the logs are located. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

While looking around `/var/log` on MacOS 10.11, I found this log file wifi.log. The following search will give you good perspective on the WiFi status change:

```
$ grep processAirPortStateChanges /var/log/wifi.log \
| grep connect \
| grep -v -e "old state=disconnected, new state=disconnected" \
-e "old state=connecting, new state=connecting" \
-e "old state=disconnected, new state=auto-join" \
-e "old state=auto-join, new state=connecting" \
| cut -d' ' -f1-5,12-
```

Sample output (yes, my new Comcast router is being flakey thus I came across this question looking for log file myself):

```
Sun Apr  3 00:46:08.540 old state=connecting, new state=4 bars
Sun Apr  3 01:46:50.509 old state=4 bars, new state=disconnected
Sun Apr  3 01:46:52.839 old state=4 bars, new state=connecting
Sun Apr  3 01:46:53.944 old state=connecting, new state=4 bars
Sun Apr  3 02:47:36.283 old state=4 bars, new state=disconnected
Sun Apr  3 02:47:37.900 old state=4 bars, new state=connecting
Sun Apr  3 02:47:38.385 old state=connecting, new state=4 bars
Sun Apr  3 03:49:38.732 old state=4 bars, new state=disconnected
Sun Apr  3 04:50:24.289 old state=4 bars, new state=disconnected
Sun Apr  3 04:50:26.313 old state=4 bars, new state=connecting
Sun Apr  3 04:50:27.026 old state=connecting, new state=4 bars
Sun Apr  3 05:51:10.288 old state=4 bars, new state=disconnected
Sun Apr  3 06:35:17.291 old state=4 bars, new state=disconnected
Sun Apr  3 06:35:19.983 old state=connecting, new state=4 bars
Sun Apr  3 08:18:36.758 old state=4 bars, new state=disconnected
Sun Apr  3 08:18:41.836 old state=4 bars, new state=connecting
Sun Apr  3 08:18:42.187 old state=connecting, new state=4 bars
```